# JavaScript - where to declare variables and define functions?

Tags: javascript

Which is better:

```
var foo = 0,
    fnFoo = function (bar)
    {
        "use strict";
        // Do stuff
    };

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    "use strict";
    fnFoo(foo);
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    "use strict";

    var foo = 0,
        fnFoo = function (bar)
        {
            "use strict";
            // Do stuff
        };

    fnFoo(foo);
});
```

The difference is the location of the variable/function declarations. In this case, assume that only the `ready` event needs to use `foo` and `fnFoo`.

Comment: `var fnFoo = function (bar) { ... };` -> `function fnFoo(bar) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only the `ready` event needs it, then put it in `ready`. That's the whole point of encapsulation. Restrict access to variables as much as possible to reduce bugs in code. What happens if you accidentally declare another `foo` or `fnFoo` by accident later on?

Not only that, but it makes your code more understandable. It means that you know exactly what each variable is used for and where.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the latter case, so 1. the vars are grouped with the code that uses them, and 2. you aren't polluting the global scope with your vars.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to wait for the document to be ready so that `jQuery` knows that the `DOM` is fully set up and thus can access form fields and other `DOM` objects. So, unless your `function` needs to access `DOM` elements, I'd declare page-wide `var`s and `functions` before the `$(document).ready(...` block, and, when you know they work move that code out into a separate script file, especially if that `function` is going to be reused in other parts of your web.

Comment: *only* if there is other code outside of the `ready` callback that also needs those functions/vars. Otherwise it should be wrapped in a jquery plugin.